# Brand New MacBook Won't Charge

Tags: mac, macbook, charging

It's just not charging anymore. I cant reset the pram because it's dead and I don't want to remove the bottom in case it voids he warranty but I need it asap. Do you know if removing the bottom voids the warranty or how else to reset the pram or any other way to fix this battery issue?

Comment: Removing the bottom doesn't void the warranty. Look in the manual that came with it. Removing the battery, however, probably does...

Comment: How "Brand New" are we talkin'? That machine does have a 1-year parts-and-labor warrantee, and 90 days phone support. Even if you're out of phone support, you could still bring it to an Apple Store and have them fix it for you for free.

Always buy AppleCare, especially with a laptop. You still might be able to. There's an education discount if you're still in college.

Oh, are you sure it's not just the power supply that's blown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took it into Apple and they said it was the cord for some reason... no idea why or what, but they gave me a new one...